# How to replace print to avoid printing NONE in output?

Tags: python

```
def sortString(string):
    if type(string)==str:
        for i in string:
            if (i>="A" and i<="Z"):
                print(i, end="")
    else:
        return("Not a string!")
print(sortString("ZOMG Hello, CS1301!!"))
```

Output:

```
ZOMGHCSNone
```

I know that I get None because of print statement that does not have to return anything on last iteration but how do I skip that? If I put return instead of print, the loop stops at first iteration.

Comment: What is the expected output? if there are numeric characters (non strings) do you want `"Not a string!"` to be printed along with the other characters? or do you only want this to trigger if the input is not a string?

Comment: Don't use `print` then. You can always `raise` an explicit error.

Comment: "Not a string!" should be printed if the string is not a string. In this case, the wanted output is just upper case letters from the string at the bottom. But I get None next to the wanted output that I can;t get rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the printout of the returned value you can replace `return("Not a string!")` with `print("Not a string!")`. Also, to check type use `isinstance`

```
def sort_string(string):
    if isinstance(string, str):
        for i in string:
            if "A" <= i <= "Z":  # simplified i>="A" and i<="Z"
                print(i, end="")
    else:
        print("Not a string!")

sort_string("ZOMG Hello, CS1301!!")
```

Output `ZOMGHCS`

You can also remove the print from inside `sortString()` and return the values as string

```
def sort_string(string):
    if isinstance(string, str):
        s = ''
        for i in string:
            if "A" <= i <= "Z":
                s += i
        return s
    else:
        return "Not a string!"

print(sort_string("ZOMG Hello, CS1301!!"))
```

Or with list comprehensions

```
def sort_string(string):
    if isinstance(string, str):
        return ''.join(i for i in string if "A" <= i <= "Z")

    return "Not a string!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work ?

```
def sortString(string):
    if type(string)==str:
        for i in string:
            if (i>="A" and i<="Z"):
                print(i, end="")
    else:
        return("Not a string!")

retVal = sortString("ZOMG Hello, CS1301!!")

if retVal :
    print(retVal)
```